# Facing error with Hive-0.10 while running a query

Tags: hadoop, hive

Facing issues with following query. Description below.

```
drop table if exists sample.dpi_short_lt;
create table sample.dpi_short_lt as
select                   b.msisdn,
                a.area_erb,
                a.longitude,
                a.latitude,
                               substring(b.msisdn,1,2) as country,
                               substring(b.msisdn,3,2) as area_code,
                               substring(b.start_time,1,4) as year,
                               substring(b.start_time,6,2) as month,
                               substring(b.start_time,9,2) as day,
                               substring(b.start_time,12,2) as hour,
                               cast(b.procedure_duration as double) as duracao_ms,
                               cast(b.internet_latency as double) as int_internet_latency,
                               cast(b.ran_latency as double) as int_ran_latency,
                               cast(b.http_latency as double) as int_http_latency,
                               (case when b.internet_latency='' then 1 else 0 end) as internet_latency_missing,
                               (case when b.ran_latency='' then 1 else 0 end) as ran_latency_missing,
                               (case when b.http_latency='' then 1 else 0 end) as http_latency_missing,
                               (cast(b.mean_throughput_ul as int) * cast( procedure_duration as int) / 1000) as total_up_bytes,
                               (cast(b.mean_throughput_dl as int) * cast(procedure_duration as int)  / 1000) as total_dl_bytes,
                               cast(b.missing_packets_ul as int) as int_missing_packets_ul,
                               cast(b.missing_packets_dl as int) as int_missing_packets_dl
from sample.dpi_large b
left outer join sample.science_new a
on b.cgi = regexp_replace(a.codigo_cgi_ecgi,'-','')
where msisdn!=''
```

;

Hive was heuristically selecting 1000 reducers and it was hanging at 99.97 percent on one reduce task. I then changed the above values to 3GB per reducer and 500 reducers and started hitting this error. for all reduce tasks.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive Runtime Error while closing operators: Unable to rename output from: hdfs://tlvcluster/tmp/hive-hadoop/hive_2014-03-01_03-14-36_812_8390586541316719852-1/_task_tmp.-ext-10001/_tmp.000003_0 to: hdfs://tlvcluster/tmp/hive-hadoop/hive_2014-03-01_03-14-36_812_8390586541316719852-1/_tmp.-ext-10001/000003_0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.close(ExecReducer.java:313)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:516)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to rename output from: hdfs://tlvcluster/tmp/hive-hadoop/hive_2014-03-01_03-14-36_812
```

I have 22 node cluster running cdh 4.3. Please try to locate what can be teh issue.